# Unable to locate package libhal-dev

Tags: apt

I receive This error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libhal-dev
...
E: Unable to locate package libhal-dev
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @muru For building virtualbox

Comment: Since both individual deb files and repositories are available (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), why do you need to build it?

Comment: @muru Becuase of this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/virtualbox-android-x86-mouse-integration-invisible-cursor-solution-4175618784/

Comment: Then see https://www.virtualbox.org/pipermail/vbox-dev/2017-February/014283.html